# Нубский вопрос по размещению блоков? Как правильно реализовать?

Tags: html, css

Есть вот такая простая конструкция:

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1024px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.block1 {
  width: 34%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
}
.block2 {
  width: 62%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: inline-block;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {
  .block1 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .block2 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block1"></div>
  <div class="block2"></div>
</div>
```

необходимо что бы при уменьшении экрана первым шел *block2*, на *bootstrap*, к примеру, знаю как это реализовать (push/pull), а как тут это правильно сделать?

Comment: стоит посмотреть класс `push/pull` в бутстрапе и сделать так же

Comment: то есть прописать стили ихние? это для двух строчек займет тонну кода,  а проще варианта нету?

Comment: конечно есть: поменять местами блоки

Comment: _это для двух строчек займет тонну кода, а проще варианта нету?_ -откуда тонна? стоит посмотреть реализацию класса `pull` или `push`

Comment: просто поменять местами блоки нельзя, порядок изначальный необходим таков как есть..

Comment: [для информации](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-floats)

Comment: дайте ответ, я его отмечу, все вышло и огромное спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно посмотреть реализацию классов `pull` в бутстрапе и сделать такие же классы у себя.

[Справка bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-floats)

```css
// Classes
.pull-left {
  float: left !important;
}
.pull-right {
  float: right !important;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Это можно сделать при помощи flexbox, а именно свойством order.